# Spring Boot - How to exclude one component during scan?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a JAR dependency that I am required to use. There is one component in that JAR that is interfering with a part of my Spring Boot application. I need to exclude that ONE component, and changing the component definition in the JAR dependency is not currently possible.

I have tried the following, but it does not work, the bean is still loaded:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false, excludeFilters = [Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = [SomeBean::class])])
```

The bean is defined as:

```
@RestController
class SomeBean {
```

NOTE: These snippets are in Kotlin.

Comment: Is the unwanted class the only class being scanned for in its package, by chance?

Comment: @Todd unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like below to skip creating bean?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {}

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    registry.removeBeanDefinition("myBeanName");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SomeBean.class })
```

Comment: Doen't work:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
        - com.somecompany.SomeBean`

Comment: I did not realise you are trying to remove some custom class. Try using maven Shade plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `@Bean`/`@Component`/etc. or `@Configuration` have any [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-condition-annotations) annotation on it (e.g.: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, `@ConditionalOnProperty`, etc.)? That would be the right solution for this problem. Can you ask the maintainer to add proper conditions? So that you (and other users) don't need to hack this around.

There is a terrible hack though: [BeanDefinitionRegistry#removeBeanDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html#removeBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-)

Comment: As I stated in my question, it is currently not possible to change the definition of the bean I want to exclude.